# Getting the music likes of my friends in FQL

Tags: permissions, facebook-fql

I'm trying to grab the music likes of my friends using the `user` and `friend` table using the following query:

```
SELECT name, music 
FROM user 
WHERE uid IN 
   (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 250)
```

It's grabbing all the names correctly, but all the music results are just "".  Does this have something to do with permissions?  If so, could you explain how to solve this and what my options are? (I'm new to FQL).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.  The issue was that I didn't get the user_likes and friend_likes permissions upon log-in.  To solve this problem, I simply added perms="user_likes, friends_likes" to my log in button:

```
        <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" 
        data-max-rows="4" perms="user_likes, friends_likes" size="xlarge">Connect</div>
```